# FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK: Caveat in docs?

Tags: android, android-activity

I know what this flag does. I was reading about task affinity and [came across the following paragraph](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack):

---

[image]

I am unable to understand the sentence,

*"If this flag causes an activity to begin a new task and the user presses the Home button to leave it, there must be some way for the user to navigate back to the task."*

Can anyone throw some light on it with an example(if possible) for what it means?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that your app provides some activity, `FooActivity`, that could be launched by some other app or by the notification manager.

Now consider what happens if the user is in `FooActivity` and presses the Home button to place `FooActivity` in the background. How does the user get back to the minimized `FooActivity` after that?

Maybe you've configured some other activity, `LaunchActivity`, to be the one that starts when you get an intent with action `MAIN` and category `LAUNCHER` (i.e. when the user taps your launcher icon). So your `LaunchActivity` (or some subsequent activity) would then have to figure out that in this situation the user wants to get back to `FooActivity`.